# Mininet & multiple distributed controllers?

Tags: sdn, mininet

I am new in Mininet and SDN. I would like to implement multiple distributed controllers in Mininet.

Is there any tutorial that can help with that?

Answer (score 0):

Mininet is used to emulate the switches and the network. Mininet comes with an in built reference controller (POX), which does not support distributed controllers.

Thus, you need to use an external controller which supports distributed instances. For example, ONOS and OpenDaylight.

I have tried it with ONOS and it works. An introductory tutorial can be found at this [link](http://sdnhub.org/tutorials/onos/experimenting-with-onos-clustering/).
Then you can connect your mininet network with the external controller using the mininet API like so

```
sudo mn --controller=remote,ip='IP address of the controller'
```

After choosing a suitable controller, a good place to start are the official wikis. Also, you might want to join the mailing lists; the developers are very active and reply to most queries.